# Capistrano 3 symlink public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano3

Im having a problem with `Capistrano 3.X`
So basically my app has public folder, where some users can upload their folders. it can be `public/a public/b` and so on. When i set linked dirs like that

`set :linked_dirs, %w{ log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public }`

I'm getting error:

```
I, [2016-01-23T05:09:48.343707 #27926]  INFO -- : Writing /home/deploy/blabla/
releases/20160123100938/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-
fe185d11a49676890d47bb783312a0cda5a44c4039214094e7957b4c040ef11c.woff2 rake 
aborted! Errno::EEXIST: File exists @ dir_s_mkdir -
/home/deploy/blabla/releases/20160123100938/public/assets 
/home/deploy/blabla/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-
3.5.2/lib/sprockets/asset.rb:163:in `write_to' 
/home/deploy/blabla/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.5.2/
lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:192:in `block (2 levels) in compile' 
/home/deploy/blabla/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-
1.0.0/lib/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:24:in `call'
```

I tried to remove assets folder, create it manually. I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

You can put users uploaded folders inside another folder like `uploaded_folders` and then

```
set :linked_dirs, %w{ log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/uploaded_folders public/system }
```

This should fix it

Comment: Hey, I know that but it's not acceptable - I have to need public/* folders because of some back-end solutions.